# Date Picker Integration with User's Google Calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker, firefox-addon, google-calendar-api

I'm looking for a date picker for my site's forms, that integrates with the end-user's Google Calendar.

For example, I want user1 to be able to log into my site, and update their orders, and if they need to put a scheduled date in a field, the interaction would look something like:

- focus into date field, or they click on a calendar icon next to the
  field
- a fully functional date picker comes up, showing a monthly calendar view from user1's Google Calendar
- inside the date picker, user1 selects a date, names the event, and clicks save
- this should write the event to user1's Google Calendar, close the date picker, and populate the selected date into the form on my website.

A typical use case would be someone that does a lot of scheduling and customer contact.  I'm looking for something that would eliminate the swivel chair that a person would normally incur, where they have to stop, look at their phone, and find an open block of time.

Preferably, this would be a date picker on a web form, but it could also be a widget on the side.

This really seems like something that there should be a FireFox plugin for, but I'm not finding one - I'm looking for something that eliminates the need for a second tab and/or second browser window.

Can someone point me in the right direction?